# How to distinguish BIM 360 vs ACC/unified projects?

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-construction-cloud

(Update: There may or may not be any such thing as a "unified project". But there is definitely a button on my Account Admin->Projects screen that says "Go to unified projects", hence my confusion. It just takes me to a list of all projects.)

Since some API endpoints are not compatible between the two types of projects, (see https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/overview/bim-360-compatibility/compatibility-table/), it would be nice to know, programmatically, which type of project you are dealing with.

The response from  https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/:hub_id/projects lists, for example, the exact same details regardless. Is there another call that would give more info?

I know that the BIM 360 projects start with "b.", but not in the above list.

Just poking around, the BIM 360 API endpoint https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/:account_id/projects apparently returns only(?) BIM 360 projects, complete with "b.". But if I want ALL projects, and simply need to know the difference? I *could* make both calls and parse the differences; but one call with the correct info would be great, if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint I meant is: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-projects-GET/. It is for project information in the general context. The one you pointed out is for getting project information in the context of BIM360.

Data Management is a general API. e.g. you manage your (as a web application) manage models and data in your own buckets (on Forge), this goes with Data Management.  BIM360 or ACC or Fusion360 etc is the platform that manages model or data for end users, in a format of more user-orientated structure like hub>>project>>folder>>item>>version etc.  These fall into Data Management.  BIM 360 API  will be more specific in the context of BIM360. e.g. Admin API (like what you are using), Issue API, RFI API, Cost API , Model Coordination API etc.

As to united project, it means the project list managed within Autodesk Construction Cloud (ACC), which includes BIM360 projects and ACC projects. In another word, a united portal to access the two types of projects. To distinguish the two types, the attribute I mentioned in the last email is the indicator.  Hope it explains.